# PDF Signature - LTV - CRL alternative?

Tags: validation, pdf, itext, signature

I'm working on a .NET PDF signature application that allows signing with a SmartCard (Belgian ID). In addition, I'd like the signature to support LTV.

I've followed the instructions and examples from iText, and it seems to work well. Acrobat Reader DC indicates that the signature is valid, and offers LTV.
There is an practical issue however: the included CRL is too big. 14MB on my test ID. This means that, for every signature, 14MB needs to be downloaded which slows down operation and significantly increases the file size of each signed PDF.

I was wondering if there is an alternative to including the complete CRL while still supporting LTV? It seems a bit overkill to include the complete CRL while the only "thing" that seems needed is the inclusion of a verifyable proof that the certificates in the chain have not been revoked at time of signing. I thought that use of the OCSP might offer such functionality, however simply removing the CRL and including a OcspClientBouncyCastle instance didn't do the trick. Is the OCSP that is given to SignDetached used to check whether the certificate is revoked at time of signing instead?

A related question concerns the LTV "support" itself. As I mentioned, Acrobat Reader only indicates that the file supports LTV when the CRL is included. Checking at the online service http://dss.nowina.lu/validation (EU reference) seems to indicate something else however. There, even the file without the embedded CRL has a valid check behind the description "Is AdES-T validation conclusive?" (which is the only checkpoint under "Long Term Validation Data"). As such, I was wondering if it is even needed to include the CRL for LTV?

Suffice to say I'm confused :).

Btw, 2 more warnings from that same verification service that I can't seem to solve: "The 'issuer-serial' attribute is absent or does not match!" and "The signer's certificate is not supported by SSCD!". But maybe thats for another question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: People can better help you if you post questions which are crisp and concise ... else wise you risk getting ignored ... think about your question and post just the next step you need to understand as your progress to the ultimate solution

Comment: Generally an alternative for CRLs are OCSP responses. Whether they are an alternative for you, depends on the services the PKI of your CA provides. If that doesn't work for you, as you claim, you might want to share a Pdf to analyze. Concerning Adobe Reader... It is not specially made for EU compatibility, so certain differences may arise.

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind for a next post.

Comment: @mkl Good to hear that OCSP should indeed provide an alternative to including the complete CRL. I believe this should work for me; a server is available at ocsp.id.belgium.be afaik. But acrobat still tells me it is not LTV.

I uploaded a test file here (without including the CRL): http://we.tl/dBFE114SAd

For that file, Acrobat indicates LTV is not available while http://dss.nowina.lu/validation seems to indicate it is.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please be aware, what Adobe calls LTV-enabled corresponds to but one ETSI LTV profile. I'll look at your file later.

Comment: Thanks mkl! Main reason I'm asking is that I find it difficult to assess the (legal) validity of the generated files. The related ETSI documents are quite hard to read for a non-expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at your sample document. It does **not** conform to any LTV profile, merely to T-Level, i.e. it is timestamped.

### In detail

The PDF signature is implemented merely by embedding a single CMS container using subfilter **ETSI.CAdES.detached** which contains

- the certificate chain of the signer certificate in the CMS container certificate set

  - C=BE,CN=Belgium Root CA2
  - C=BE,CN=Citizen CA,SERIALNUMBER=201103
  - C=BE,CN=Donny Tytgat (Signature),SURNAME=Tytgat,GIVENNAME=Donny Geert,SERIALNUMBER=81032305309);
- a signed Adobe `RevocationInfoArchival` attribute containing a single good OCSP response for the signer certificate; the response is signed by

  - CN=Belgium OCSP Responder,C=BE

  which has the `id-pkix-ocsp-nocheck` extension;
- a signature time stamp signed by

  - C=BE,SERIALNUMBER=2014,O=Belgium Federal Government,CN=Time Stamping Authority

Thus, the signature conforms to Baseline T-Level as

> A PAdES signature conformant to T-Level **shall** be a signature conformant to B-Level for which a Trust Service
>   Provider [i.4] has generated a trusted token (time-mark or time-stamp token) proving that the signature itself actually
>   existed at a certain date and time.
>
> *(section 7 - Requirements for T-Level Conformance - [ETSI TS 103 172 V2.2.2](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103100_103199/103172/02.02.02_60/ts_103172v020202p.pdf))*

where B-Level conformance is defined as

> This clause defines requirements that PAdES signatures claiming conformance to the B-Level have to fulfil.
>   The current clause specifies compliance requirements for short-term electronic signatures.
>
> This clause actually profiles
>   PAdES-BES (signatures that do not incorporate signature-policy-identifier) and PAdES-EPES (signatures
>   that do incorporate signature-policy-identifier) signatures.
>
> *(section 6 - Requirements for B-Level Conformance - ibidem)*

(Additional requirements also are fulfilled.)

---

It does **not** conform to LT-Level which requires:

> The generator shall include the full set of revocation data (CRL or OCSP responses) that have been used in the
>   validation of the signer, and CA certificates used in signature. This set includes all certificate status
>   information required for validating the signing certificate, for validating any attribute certificate present in the
>   signature, and for validating any time-stamp token's signing certificate (i.e. a TSA certificate) already
>   incorporated to the signature.
>
> *(section 8 - Requirements for LT-Level Conformance - ibidem)*

as there is no revocation information concerning the CA certificate or the TSA certificate.

Thus, it can also **not** conform to LTA-Level as

> A PAdES signature conformant to LTA-Level **shall** be a signature conformant to LT-Level to which one or more
>   document-time-stamp has been incorporated

### Concerning other questions

> I was wondering if there is an alternative to including the complete CRL while still supporting LTV? It seems a bit overkill to include the complete CRL while the only "thing" that seems needed is the inclusion of a verifyable proof that the certificates in the chain have not been revoked at time of signing. I thought that use of the OCSP might offer such functionality

Given an appropriate PKI infrastructure that is possible. Unfortunately, though, neither the CA not the TSA certificate contain information on a OCSP responder responsible for them. Thus, either the Belgium citizen PKI does not provide OCSP services for those certificates or it merely does not make that provision public.

BTW, this is what the Diagnostic Tree remarks

```
<Message Id="0">OSCP Uri not found in certificate meta-data !</Message>
```

are about which you get when verifying your signature using the http://dss.nowina.lu/validation service.

> There, even the file without the embedded CRL has a valid check behind the description "Is AdES-T validation conclusive?" (which is the only checkpoint under "Long Term Validation Data").

This user interface layout has misled you, as mentioned above there are more requirements for LTV-related profiles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this mkl! Very clear explanation.

I guess there's nothing much I can do then about the PDF file size if LTV is needed in this context.
In order to tackle the delay due to downloading CRLs; I guess I can write an in-between layer for the CrlOnlineClient that caches CRL retrievals if the local version is still valid. This would at least limit the download delay that the regular CrlOnlineClient causes.

Comment: You could check whether the Belgium citizen pki does provide ocsp services for the ca and tsa certificates but merely does not say so. In that case a better solution can be implemented...

Comment: @mkl is there any clear specification of timing of CLR/OCSP requests in relationship to the timing of the signatures? In other words, should I renew CLR/OCSP requests at each signature or I can cache previously fetched responses?

Comment: *"any clear specification of timing of CLR/OCSP requests in relationship to the timing of the signatures"* - that depends on the validation model to apply which in turn depends on the legal context in which your signatures shall be valid. Are you e.g. creating signatures according to EU eIDAS? Or in some US context, e.g. in the US health sector? Or where are you?

Comment: BTW, the technical specification ETSI TS 103 172 used in this answer meanwhile has been replaced by the European norm ETSI EN 319 142 as current specification of the baseline profiles.